# FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'photo' into field. Choices are: caption, date_added, id, image, name, slug, source

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Why cant I use `photo__slug=photo_slug` in the line of code below:

`photo = get_object_or_404(Photo, photo__slug=photo_slug)`

I keep getting this same error:
    `FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'photo' into field. Choices are: caption, date_added,     id, image, name, slug, source`

Comment: How could we possibly know? You haven't given us any details of your models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is telling you everything you need to know. 'photo' isn't a property on the object you're accessing. try:

```
photo = get_object_or_404(Photo, slug=slug)
```